# How to create iPhone Application for my flash page?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I want to make iPhone application for my flash page.

What is the easiest way? Does PhoneGap support that kind of things?

EDIT:
The application needs to open the flash page like a browser, similar as the Photon app.

Comment: Please read the FAQ *before* posting!

Comment: Please post more information. What do you mean by 'flash page'? What are your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is not supported on iOS. The answer is you can’t create one.
Here’s Steve Jobs’ article on the reasons why it is not supported — http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

Comment: Not true. Besides that, that's an article from 2010. There are plenty flash-supported browsers -- http://ipod.about.com/od/bestiphoneapps/tp/Top-iPhone-Flash-Browsers.htm

Comment: Yes. But when you create a `UIWebView` inside a native app, you get a trimmed down version of Safari, which does not support Flash. So, your app (phonegap or not) will never have Flash in it. Also this is what it says on the link you shared "It achieves this by connecting your iPhone to a remote computer running Flash and then streams its desktop to you.” You can probably achieve it by doing something similar.

Comment: I don't want to have a flash in it, just to open a flash page. Currently, I've downloaded this Photon application and I'm seeing my flash page on my iPhone. I'm just wondering how to make an application like that.

Comment: It achieves this by connecting your iPhone to a remote computer running Flash and then streams its desktop to you. You can probably achieve it by doing something similar.